# How to use regular expression clear content inside div

Tags: expression, element

I have this code

```
<div class="kakaa">
    <div class="hihi">
        <div>dfsfsdf</div>
        <div class="haha">
            <div id="kaka">ohfoehwf</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, i want to remove div has class hihi, how to do it become

```
<div class="kakaa">
    <div class="main">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You definitely [shouldn't be using regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/540162) (unless you're 1001% sure you know what you're doing).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if you're doing this on server-side or client-side. If client-side, no regex is necessary. Use jQuery:

```
$('.hihi').remove();
```

Here's a reference: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

If you're doing it server-side, don't use regex (you'll never be able to cover all the possibilities in an HTML tag with regex). Instead use a HTML DOM parser. Here's a very simple one: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I use simplehtmldom parse another site, but in the simplehtmldom can get html or content each block, not support remove tag same as above